# Java - Rotate image keeps failing

Tags: java, image, rotation, jpanel, repaint

I've been stuck with this problem for hours now. I've got a JPanel to which I draw several pictures.

It's a 2D game, I keep printing everything to the screen by simply using repaint();.

At some point, I want to draw a man firing a pistol. Everything works fine so far, but only if the man looks at the north-direction because my animation-pictures are all drawn to the north. Rotating them manually and pasting them into my project after that would make it way too far, so I've decided to rotate the image to make it useable in any direction, but I can't figure out how to do it. Here's some code:

A simple switch in this method checks for the current facing-direction. Note, that the first case (NORTH) is working fine, because the pictures are drawn to the north as default.

```
switch(CharDirection){
        case NORTH:
            if(PistolAnim == 0){
            try {
                Man = ImageIO.read(ManNorthURL);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }else{
                try{
                    if(PistolAnim == 1){
                    Man = ImageIO.read(Shoot1URL);
                    PistolAnim = 2;
                    return;
                    }
                    if(PistolAnim == 2){
                    Man = ImageIO.read(Shoot2URL);
                    PistolAnim = 3;
                    return;
                    }
                    if(PistolAnim ==3){
                    Man = ImageIO.read(Shoot3URL);
                    PistolAnim = 0;
                    return;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e){

                }
            }
            break;
        case EAST:
            if(PistolAnim == 0){
                try {
                    Man = ImageIO.read(ManEastURL);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }else{
                    try{
                        if(PistolAnim == 1){    
                        Man = ImageIO.read(Shoot1URL);
                        PistolAnim = 2;
                        return;
                        }
                        if(PistolAnim == 2){
                        Man = ImageIO.read(Shoot2URL);
                        PistolAnim = 3;
                        return;
                        }
                        if(PistolAnim ==3){
                        Man = ImageIO.read(Shoot3URL);
                        PistolAnim = 0;
                        return;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e){

                    }
                }
            break;
```

The integer variable "PistolAnim" is for showing the state of the animation. 0 - no animation ongoing
1 - Picture 1

2 - Picture 2

3 - Picture 3

The paint function (well, the important part) looks like this:

```
g.drawImage(Man, CharX, CharY, Man.getWidth(), Man.getHeight(), null);
```

I've tried to use the following rotation method:

```
public void rotate(double Degrees, BufferedImage img1){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img1);
        BufferedImage BlankCanvas = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)BlankCanvas.getGraphics();
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(Degrees), icon.getIconWidth()/2, icon.getIconHeight()/2);



        g2d.drawImage(img1, 100, 100, null);
        img1 = BlankCanvas;
    }
```

I found it on the internet and it worked in some tests of mine, but now it isn't doing what it should do. I inserted the line

```
rotation(90, Man);
```

at almost every point of my code, but nothing works. I can't rotate the whole Graphics2D object in paint (it's called g) either, because it draws other pictures as well.

Anybody got an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use AffineTransform class  to rotate this image.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: Why not? I mean it works just fine?

Comment: It the Java standard. Have you ever seen an example in a textbook or Swing tutorial that uses upper cases?  An upper case character indicates a "class name". Look at the highlighting done by the forum. Learn by example and don't make up your own conventions if you want to ask questions and have people read your code. It is confusing to try an read your code.

Comment: I think if you don't manage to realize which of these names are variables, IT is not the right thing for you. Also I wrote that e.g. "PistolAnim" is a (int) variable. So what shoudl be confusing? You just need to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)BlankCanvas.getGraphics();
```

This code is wrong. You should NOT use the getGraphics() method. You should do your custom painting from within the `paintComponent()` method of your JPanel and use the Graphics object that is passed to this method. Then when you invoke the "rotate(...)` method you pass this Graphics object to the method and use it to paint the rotated image.

Instead of worrying about the rotation/translation code, you could just use the [Rotated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/). Then you can paint the icon using the `paintIcon(...)` method:

```
RotatedIcon rotated = new RotatedIcon(icon, degrees);
rotated.paintIcon(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! There's just one thing I don't really get... What should I do with my rotate() method? Should I completely replace the content with those two lines?

Answer (score 0):

The method below will rotate your BufferedImage to specific angle specified by you. You can use this method to rotate the image.

```
//method for rotating the image to a specific angle 
    public BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage image, double angle) {
        //calculate the new size of the rotated image
        double rad = Math.toRadians(angle);
        double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(rad));
        double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(rad));
        int newWidth = (int) Math.floor(image.getWidth() * cos + image.getHeight() * sin);
        int newHeight = (int) Math.floor(image.getHeight() * cos + image.getWidth() * sin);
        //createding a new bufferedimage with size that will have rotated image
        BufferedImage rotated = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
        //we set the information of how much will the image be 
       //displaced in x an y axis during the transform operation
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.translate((newWidth - image.getWidth()) / 2, (newHeight - image.getHeight()) / 2);
        //calculate the center of transformation
        int coordX = image.getWidth() / 2;
        int coordY = image.getHeight() / 2;
        //setting the center and angle information for rotate operation 
        at.rotate(rad, coordX, coordY);
        //executing the rotate operation
        AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
        rotated = scaleOp.filter(image, rotated);
        return rotated;
    }
```

After rotating the image to angle you desire you can draw the image.

```
BufferedImage rotatedImage = rotateImage(image,90);
//draw image
```

Comment: Hi Rando Shtishi, welcome. Please consider adding a more detailed explanation.